# Is it safe if I use the same Google Recaptcha site key and secret key on 2 different servers?

Tags: google, web-development, security, captcha

I have 2 servers, staging server and production server. Server staging is used for testing my website. While the production server is for live website

Now I use the same site key and secret key for my website on both servers

Do I need to create different site keys and secret keys of google recaptcha for the two servers? Or it does not need to be done?

Answer (score 1):

If they are both using the same domain, I doubt it is possible to create a second set of keys.  I know this is an old question, but did you try it?  I suspect you will get some sort of `duplicate` error.

If you did come up with an answer to your own question, please post it here so the information is available for future users.